# How to send a response to multiple answer question on a Google Form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I work for a charter school and when I get new students I have to fill out an equipment request form for the student through Google Forms. I would like to be able to automatically submit a response without having to fill the form out every time. I already have all the information about the student that I would need in a Google Sheet.
I **do not** have edit access to the Form and can only use Google app script for coding because I do not have server access or admin access on my work laptop. So this is really my only option for automation.
So far I have been able to make a fetch call with the Form url and an object using the entryIDs for the questions.

```
const obj = {
"entry.1111": tName,
"entry.2222": sFirst,
"entry.3333": sLast,
"entry.4444": 'Option 1', //multiple answer question
"entry.5555": 'yes',
"entry.6666": 'yes',
"entry.7777": 'minor',
"entry.8888": 'initial'
}
const options = {
  'method': 'post',
  'payload': obj
}
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
```

This works as long as I do not need to include more than one answer per question, but for some students I need to do just that. If I try to send a string like "Option 1, Option 2" the script fails.

Edit: My code **does not** have the comment in the object.

Comment: have you tried an array for payload?

Comment: Yes I have. ['Option 1', 'Option 2'] fails. I know this how it is done when using the Google services.

Comment: Can I ask you about the question on Google Form that you want to send the multiple answers to? For example, if the question is the radio button, 1 option can be selected. If my understanding is correct, when the other option is included, I thought that the text of `Option 1, Option 2` might be able to be sent. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: The question uses the checkbox input method. It has three options and any combination of the three may be selected.

Comment: Have you checked the different methods on [Class FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response)? Is the script you are using a standalone one, or is it paired with the sheet you have the student data from? Is this the entire script?

Comment: Thank you for providing more information. From your additional information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Kessy Yes I did look at the FormResponse class, however since I don't have access to the Google Form I can't use any of them. I know how to send multiple answers using FormApp and Items. The script is linked to a sheet that holds the student info. This is most of the script, I only omitted the url and variable declarations. There is also a menu item to run the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the multiple answers for one question are sent, unfortunately, I thought that JSON object might not be able to be directly used for the payload. Because the same key is used in this case. And, even when the array is used for the value, an error occurs. This has already been mentioned in your comment.

So in this answer, I would like to propose to add it to the query parameter. In this case, I think that there are 2 patterns for your situation.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, all values are used as the query parameters.

```js
// This script is from https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/70503e0ea6998083fcb05c6d2a857107
String.prototype.addQuery = function(obj) {
  return this + Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(p, e, i) {
    return p + (i == 0 ? "?" : "&") +
      (Array.isArray(obj[e]) ? obj[e].reduce(function(str, f, j) {
        return str + e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(f) + (j != obj[e].length - 1 ? "&" : "")
      },"") : e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[e]));
  },"");
}

function myFunction() {
  const url = "### your URL ###"; // Please set your URL.
  const query = {
    "entry.1111": tName,
    "entry.2222": sFirst,
    "entry.3333": sLast,
    "entry.4444": ['Option 1', 'Option 2'],
    "entry.5555": 'yes',
    "entry.6666": 'yes',
    "entry.7777": 'minor',
    "entry.8888": 'initial'
  };
  const endpoint = url.addQuery(query);
  const options = {'method': 'post'};
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, options);
  console.log(res.getContentText());
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, only the question of the multiple answers is sent as the query parameters.

```js
// This script is from https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/70503e0ea6998083fcb05c6d2a857107
String.prototype.addQuery = function(obj) {
  return this + Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(p, e, i) {
    return p + (i == 0 ? "?" : "&") +
      (Array.isArray(obj[e]) ? obj[e].reduce(function(str, f, j) {
        return str + e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(f) + (j != obj[e].length - 1 ? "&" : "")
      },"") : e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[e]));
  },"");
}

function myFunction() {
  const url = "### your URL ###"; // Please set your URL.
  const query = {
    "entry.4444": ['Option 1', 'Option 2'],
  };
  const obj = {
    "entry.1111": tName,
    "entry.2222": sFirst,
    "entry.3333": sLast,
    "entry.5555": 'yes',
    "entry.6666": 'yes',
    "entry.7777": 'minor',
    "entry.8888": 'initial'
  };
  const endpoint = url.addQuery(query);
  const options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': obj
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, options);
  console.log(res.getContentText())
}
```

Comment: These do not work for me. I get a blank response, like I get a timestamp for a response but all the response fields are blank.

Comment: @Andrew Valenzuela Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I get a blank response, like I get a timestamp for a response but all the response fields are blank.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? Because when I tested above 2 patterns, I could confirm that all answers are put to the Spreadsheet. I apologize for this.

Comment: Yes 100% my fault. I tried your code but used the wrong entry IDs when testing. After fixing I can confirm it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Andrew Valenzuela Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.